# ¿Como puedo llamar varias ids y datos de diferentes tablas en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en este mundo de la programacion, y me toco arreglar un codigo en php puro y javascript, el detalle es que parece que la base de datos antigua manejaba todo en una sola tabla, y en el actual proyecto que se esta desarrollando, tenemos multiples tablas, y no se como llamarlas para usar sus columnas, este es mi codigo:

```
        var params = {
                TableName : "grupos",
                ExpressionAttributeNames:{
                "id": "grupo_id"
                },
                };
```

document.getElementById('grupo_id').addEventListener('change', function() {

```
            let datos = this.value;
            let e = document.getElementById("grupo_id");
            let grupo = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHtml;
            let parts = datos.split('|');
            let id = parts[0];

            document.getElementById('groupInfo').innerHTML += grupo + ":<br>";
            document.getElementById('capacity').textContent = parts[1];
            document.getElementById('placesAvailable').textContent = parts[2];
            //let days = parts[1].split(',');                    
        });
```

ese grupo_id es de una tabla llamada grupos, pero antes era llamado IdGrupo, y este antiguo estaba mezclado con todo lo demas en una sola tabla, tuve la idea de usar un var, pero igual no jala los datos de la tabla grupos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacerlo con clases y querySelector, asignale una misma clase a todos los elementos que quieras manipular, por que si lo haces con id te va a seleccionar siempre el primero solamente.

```
document.querySellectorAll(".claseAsignada")
```

Comment: tengo que asignarle clases a los datos de las tablas? Cómo haría eso?